# What is the previous value in this loop?

Tags: c++

Here is part of my code. The rest is just the function definitions. I have an array of 20 x 20 that records the temperature of a plate. I need to reiterate through a loop until no cell in the array changes more than 0.1 degree (I refresh the values through every iteration) How would you monitor the largest change for any cell in an array in order to determine when to stop iterating? Right now I have tried this, but it doesn't output correctly. I believe it is because I am incorrectly defining my previous one to compare the current one with.

```
while (true)
{
    bool update = false;
    for (int a = 1; a < array_size -1; a++)
    {
        for (int b = 1; b < array_size -1; b++)
        {             
            hot_plate[a][b] = sum_cell(hot_plate, a, b);

        }
    } 

    for (int a = 1; a < array_size-1; a++)
    {
        for (int b = 1; b < array_size-1; b++)
        {
            hot_plate_next[a][b]=sum_cell(hot_plate_next, a,b);
            if (abs(hot_plate_next[a][b] - hot_plate[a][b]) > 0.1)
            {
                update = true;
            }
            hot_plate_next[a][b] = hot_plate[a][b];
            cout << hot_plate[a][b] << " ";
        }  
    }

    if (!update) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the best way to output this code cleanly in rows and columns using cout without it being a mess?

Comment: Try adding the suggested line in my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

When you put:

```
        if (abs(hot_plate_next[a][b] - hot_plate[a][b]) < 0.1)
        {
            update = false;
        }
```

inside the 2nd nested for-loop, you are setting "update" to false if ANY of the cells have a difference less than 0.1 between current and previous checks, instead of ALL cells like you wanted.

Update your code as follows:

```
    bool update = false;
```

and

```
    if (abs(hot_plate_next[a][b] - hot_plate[a][b]) > 0.1)
    {
        update = true;
    }
```

(I would have put >=, but you said "until no cell in the array changes more than 0.1 degree")

Edit as per request: to output the matrix cleanly, add the following line:

```
 cout << "\n";
```

here:

```
for (int a = 1; a < array_size-1; a++)
{
    for (int b = 1; b < array_size-1; b++)
    {
        hot_plate_next[a][b]=sum_cell(hot_plate_next, a,b);
        if (abs(hot_plate_next[a][b] - hot_plate[a][b]) > 0.1)
        {
            update = true;
        }
        hot_plate_next[a][b] = hot_plate[a][b];
        cout << hot_plate[a][b] << " ";
    }  
    cout << "\n"; // Add this line
}
```

Comment: I am skipping the edges. They are constant set to another value in the code.

Comment: Found the problem - see update.

Comment: I updated the code. When I run it, it seems that the code doesn't loop enough. It is supposed to loop until it becomes stable. I can post all of code if needed.

Comment: Note the "update = true;" change inside the if clause.

Comment: dang i am just not sure. I just get an infinite loop when I run

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you overwrite `update` when a cell has a *smaller* change. In that case, any cell that has a smaller change will stop the iteration.

Structure your loop like this:

```
float largest_change = 0.0f;
do {
    largest_change = 0.0f;

    for (...) {
        float new_value = ...
        float change = abs(new_value - hot_plate[a][b]);
        if (change > largest_change)
            largest_change = change;
        hot_plate[a][b] = change;
    }
} while (largestChange > 0.1f);
```

Comment: (abs(hot_plate_next[a][b] - hot_plate[a][b]) < 0.1) may not necessarily evaluate to true for the last cell, in which case it would not affect whether the computation stops or not (update could have been set to false by an earlier cell)

Comment: I agree completely. I like your answer, by the way.